# Transient attribute not found in entity

Tags: core-data, attributes, transient

I'm trying to get the first letter of an attribute (autor) from my pre populated sqlite database. I have no problems retriving data from the database using coredata. But when I try to get data from my transient property, I get this error message: "NSFetchedResultsController ERROR: object { Autor = "\U00cdtalo Calvino"; } returned nil value for section name key path 'FirstLetter'. Object will be placed in unnamed section"...

I have created a transient attribute called FirstLetter and inside my entity Cit. I have also my class for the entity defined.

#### Cit.h

```
@interface Cit : NSManagedObject {
@private
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * Autor;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * FirstLetter;
- (NSString *) FirstLetter;
@end
```

#### Cit.m

```
#import "Cit.h"
@implementation Cit
@dynamic Autor;
@dynamic FirstLetter;

- (NSString *) FirstLetter {
    NSLog(@"doing");
    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"FirstLetter"];
    NSString * initial = [[self valueForKey:@"Autor"] substringToIndex:1];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"FirstLetter"];
    return initial;
}
@end
```

I cannot get the it to work. Does anyone have a solution for that??? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar in my model class, but I didn't bother creating a transient object in the model. I just added a `- (NSString *)sectionIndex` method to my model that returned the first letter of the string, same as you.

So, I'd try deleting the transient attribute from your model and see if that works any better.